# Add pointer to the bottom of a div as a continuation of its background image

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to stack divs, with a pointer leading into the next div that is a continuation of the previous div's background image.

I've looked around and I've seen some options, but in all of them the bottom div has to be a solid color. 
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/nhqKb/

```css
#container{
    height: 300px;
    background: url('http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7358/9532233404_58763bd668_b.jpg') no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#one {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid green;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

#two {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid green;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
    
    
</div>
```

Is there any way to implement this using divs with background images instead of solid colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use skewX and pseudo elements to make this.

```
#container {
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440635592348-167b1b30296f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=a029f986631f264fdbc8c0272cab9c40') no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#one:before,
#one:after {
  background-color: inherit;
  bottom: 100%;
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
#one:before {
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
#one:after {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! I'm still having trouble figuring out how the bottom div will have a background image? It seems like this will only work with the bottom div having a solid color.

Comment: @Cassandra Hi, I made changes to the code and I used the same image from the bar for the pointer and place it in the exact position. https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/g9evbtna/